# How to add controller to Custom Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive, and also I have a controller in a separate file. I know I can add a controller to this directive in this way

```
   .directive("languageFooter", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "templates/footer.html",
            controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {..}
        };
    });
```

But I was wondering if it's possible to add a controller that I have in a separate file something like this

```
     .directive("languageFooter", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "templates/footer.html",
            controller: "customController"
        };
    });
```

Comment: ofcourse you can add this way also.... All you have to do is load the controller file before the directive file...

Comment: Even second approach is more recommended, as you are not defining controller inline, thus it can be reused.

Comment: Thanks Guys, it was pretty simple

Comment: @Alex Can you tell how and from where does customController get called? As in where is it supposed to be stored? Like a function or does it need to be defined with app.controller(customController.... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ofcourse add controller this way. only thing is that you should load the controller js file before directive js file. Also as per Kulbhushan comment, the second approach is more in practice